# translate a mysql query into nhibernate

Tags: mysql, nhibernate

Please, can you help me to translate such a mysql query into nhibernate:

```
SELECT sales_id, service_id,dayofyear(dt), max(dt) FROM clients.statistics group by sales_id, service_id,dayofyear(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

sales_id is a property of Sales class, service_id is a property of Service class

Answer (score 0):

If you have a working SQL query, you can use that with the Hibernate directly. Hibernate can execute those queries, and wrap the query result as objects.

See [this doc about mapping a entity class on SQL query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13696). That is from normal Hibernate (not NHibernate) but something similar should work in your case.

First make a class that holds the result from query (eg Result) and contains references to required entities (Sales and Service)

```
String sql = "SELECT sales_id, service_id,dayofyear(dt), max(dt) "
    "FROM clients.statistics " +
    "group by sales_id, service_id, dayofyear(dt)";
sess.createSQLQuery(sql).addEntity("result", Result.class)
    .addJoin("result.sales").addJoin("result.services");
```

Comment: tnks, but can you explain how to write this SQL by use of criteria of nHibernate?